# Extracting an object among many, from JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

My JSON file (5000 in total) looks like this

```
{"version":1.2,"people":[{"pose_keypoints_2d":[0,0,0,1383.9,318.242,0.892951,1427.93,327.25,0.828307,1445.77,409.619,0.952105,1416.18,397.863,0.090918,1345.49,306.583,0.789117,0,0,0,0,0,0,1377.87,459.777,0.824136,1404.51,471.452,0.745714,0,0,0,0,0,0,1345.6,459.6,0.731992,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1421.95,271.437,0.540316,1377.91,268.169,0.306764,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[1516.22,174.003,0.932503,1507.48,224.333,0.864362,1451.52,221.257,0.883005,1413.29,291.958,0.80518,1463.28,291.779,0.867427,1563.37,238.898,0.84872,1569.37,321.275,0.825046,1566.2,394.961,0.864594,1495.57,412.46,0.804823,1466.11,409.65,0.698038,1454.5,527.379,0.146485,0,0,0,1528.09,412.567,0.733411,1516.28,530.372,0.196314,0,0,0,1504.51,156.44,0.878404,1525.11,159.409,0.852905,1492.74,159.449,0.567964,1542.82,171.264,0.637156,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[630.433,247.712,0.887763,621.52,297.744,0.898341,580.278,297.779,0.803383,600.839,380.229,0.766635,624.594,324.31,0.850614,665.583,294.92,0.862791,677.475,377.217,0.792423,644.959,389.091,0.861932,630.352,459.596,0.708987,606.759,459.742,0.639099,612.697,580.392,0.424434,594.964,809.933,0.445884,659.764,456.741,0.742195,653.902,577.364,0.655682,648.036,689.252,0.638049,621.585,241.786,0.917391,642.178,238.881,0.869318,597.994,244.66,0.8782,648.082,238.926,0.0987843,674.549,715.811,0.559119,677.444,712.729,0.545488,642.173,695.197,0.447904,648.119,833.326,0.4606,639.217,836.383,0.40265,583.314,830.54,0.387601],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[0,0,0,1024.74,274.253,0.879164,1071.92,280.108,0.773811,1092.51,365.365,0.638758,0,0,0,977.61,271.255,0.881595,974.632,342.017,0.124485,0,0,0,1018.81,439.052,0.685377,1048.31,441.989,0.674454,1039.42,553.779,0.665407,1018.85,662.676,0.66249,980.631,436.208,0.673822,983.535,547.897,0.543447,974.669,647.981,0.465162,0,0,0,0,0,0,1068.95,224.063,0.535875,1021.84,215.334,0.331974,989.444,665.68,0.120769,962.987,650.998,0.121694,971.792,665.614,0.374614,1036.49,668.732,0.40357,1036.47,671.618,0.45803,1007.05,671.574,0.609372],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[1133.66,156.449,0.871671,1160.14,200.52,0.909641,1119.08,194.716,0.881631,1101.34,250.727,0.741804,1095.47,306.6,0.554203,1189.7,206.51,0.863547,1210.3,294.77,0.795075,1201.36,359.55,0.150867,1142.45,356.582,0.705377,1118.83,350.711,0.660271,1118.81,450.822,0.10509,0,0,0,1166.08,359.521,0.703378,1160.13,439.008,0.0764702,0,0,0,1124.82,150.485,0.869508,1142.39,150.587,0.958235,0,0,0,1166.1,150.462,0.915307,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[1327.76,344.854,0.7714,1230.79,412.576,0.777522,1186.54,430.265,0.710346,1166.08,574.291,0.745479,1286.74,551.003,0.859514,1274.9,400.802,0.615538,1333.89,500.898,0.732315,1330.99,406.568,0.842077,1251.33,692.147,0.54616,1213.11,695.104,0.558347,1195.5,874.656,0.59577,1151.27,1045.3,0.537499,1283.75,689.225,0.499876,1260.23,868.795,0.569042,1213.25,1018.88,0.64621,1310.24,338.859,0.914034,0,0,0,1260.32,342.03,0.923518,0,0,0,1283.71,1048.34,0.615529,1283.79,1045.27,0.588761,1201.34,1030.64,0.34822,1218.98,1054.23,0.162428,0,0,0,1139.5,1051.25,0.387906],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[851.14,230.059,0.836269,907,300.74,0.759377,886.42,294.972,0.670902,880.598,377.227,0.139703,839.35,365.599,0.321698,927.62,306.627,0.803614,921.722,409.668,0.740124,854.059,388.947,0.874953,886.524,486.13,0.63616,883.497,483.296,0.584742,903.968,624.47,0.744024,912.915,739.165,0.769062,895.273,489.101,0.678105,880.593,627.447,0.80521,880.369,789.348,0.833229,0,0,0,859.958,221.314,0.9495,0,0,0,901.129,227.162,0.8659,821.619,812.882,0.762655,839.321,818.779,0.748007,886.466,809.794,0.762739,865.847,745.129,0.178172,0,0,0,927.672,745.158,0.699705],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[1748.81,400.745,0.865472,1769.41,480.169,0.60199,1692.83,453.801,0.777207,1636.84,571.465,0.602594,1622.26,674.491,0.237392,1831.2,512.658,0.44287,1751.68,715.693,0.0641964,0,0,0,1689.96,718.654,0.295779,1645.81,703.916,0.317921,1607.49,854.024,0.214191,1572.18,1001.31,0.419405,1734.12,733.402,0.223622,1613.47,856.961,0.100664,1580.98,1010.01,0.141665,1745.88,377.234,0.802295,1772.39,397.828,0.831415,0,0,0,1819.34,433.244,0.858218,1489.73,1024.81,0.22791,1498.66,1036.55,0.219253,1589.85,1030.66,0.174787,1492.65,1024.84,0.494689,1492.73,1021.76,0.468759,1586.97,1024.84,0.321146],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[0,0,0,547.977,341.978,0.246313,536.227,341.878,0.601369,550.96,450.742,0.778364,615.651,424.273,0.762666,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,580.284,530.316,0.318203,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[1831.27,265.312,0.718134,1781.17,291.987,0.733738,1748.81,294.957,0.794407,1719.31,388.954,0.679386,1748.76,418.448,0.11695,1822.32,288.843,0.617834,0,0,0,0,0,0,1754.63,441.953,0.0559453,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1825.18,247.9,0.881403,1834.11,247.735,0.108933,1790.05,247.868,0.858578,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,577.393,527.334,0.376305,580.359,671.567,0.278565,618.596,692.074,0.379358,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,624.434,700.97,0.323246],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,580.365,533.218,0.257544,600.889,686.267,0.313003,600.939,809.808,0.41703,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,650.978,833.455,0.42398,648.014,827.561,0.372851,589.17,830.452,0.229458,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]},{"pose_keypoints_2d":[930.432,177.066,0.270157,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,927.496,174.034,0.370837,0,0,0,903.997,174.152,0.297842,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]}],"part_candidates":[{"0":[1133.66,156.449,0.871671,1516.22,174.003,0.932503,930.432,177.066,0.270157,851.14,230.059,0.836269,630.433,247.712,0.887763,1831.27,265.312,0.718134,1327.76,344.854,0.7714,1748.81,400.745,0.865472],"1":[1160.14,200.52,0.909641,1507.48,224.333,0.864362,1024.74,274.253,0.879164,1781.17,291.987,0.733738,621.52,297.744,0.898341,907,300.74,0.759377,1383.9,318.242,0.892951,547.977,341.978,0.246313,1230.79,412.576,0.777522,1769.41,480.169,0.60199,1869.48,553.935,0.143333],"2":[1119.08,194.716,0.881631,1451.52,221.257,0.883005,1071.92,280.108,0.773811,886.42,294.972,0.670902,1748.81,294.957,0.794407,580.278,297.779,0.803383,1427.93,327.25,0.828307,536.227,341.878,0.601369,1186.54,430.265,0.710346,1692.83,453.801,0.777207,1922.51,533.203,0.0694578],"3":[1101.34,250.727,0.741804,1413.29,291.958,0.80518,1092.51,365.365,0.638758,880.598,377.227,0.139703,600.839,380.229,0.766635,1719.31,388.954,0.679386,1445.77,409.619,0.952105,550.96,450.742,0.778364,1636.84,571.465,0.602594,1166.08,574.291,0.745479],"4":[1463.28,291.779,0.867427,1095.47,306.6,0.554203,624.594,324.31,0.850614,839.35,365.599,0.321698,1416.18,397.863,0.090918,1748.76,418.448,0.11695,615.651,424.273,0.762666,1286.74,551.003,0.859514,1622.26,674.491,0.237392],"5":[1189.7,206.51,0.863547,1563.37,238.898,0.84872,977.61,271.255,0.881595,1822.32,288.843,0.617834,665.583,294.92,0.862791,927.62,306.627,0.803614,1345.49,306.583,0.789117,545.017,338.899,0.173114,1274.9,400.802,0.615538,1831.2,512.658,0.44287],"6":[1210.3,294.77,0.795075,1569.37,321.275,0.825046,974.632,342.017,0.124485,677.475,377.217,0.792423,921.722,409.668,0.740124,1333.89,500.898,0.732315,1751.68,715.693,0.0641964,1734.09,736.304,0.0629545,1704.59,974.704,0.0607181],"7":[1201.36,359.55,0.150867,644.959,389.091,0.861932,854.059,388.947,0.874953,1566.2,394.961,0.864594,1330.99,406.568,0.842077,1704.67,662.737,0.0836309],"8":[1142.45,356.582,0.705377,1495.57,412.46,0.804823,1018.81,439.052,0.685377,1754.63,441.953,0.0559453,630.352,459.596,0.708987,1377.87,459.777,0.824136,886.524,486.13,0.63616,580.284,530.316,0.318203,1251.33,692.147,0.54616,1689.96,718.654,0.295779,1863.57,992.377,0.0562326],"9":[1118.83,350.711,0.660271,1466.11,409.65,0.698038,1048.31,441.989,0.674454,606.759,459.742,0.639099,1404.51,471.452,0.745714,883.497,483.296,0.584742,577.393,527.334,0.376305,1213.11,695.104,0.558347,1645.81,703.916,0.317921],"10":[1118.81,450.822,0.10509,1454.5,527.379,0.146485,1039.42,553.779,0.665407,612.697,580.392,0.424434,903.968,624.47,0.744024,580.359,671.567,0.278565,1607.49,854.024,0.214191,1195.5,874.656,0.59577],"11":[1018.85,662.676,0.66249,618.596,692.074,0.379358,912.915,739.165,0.769062,594.964,809.933,0.445884,1572.18,1001.31,0.419405,1151.27,1045.3,0.537499],"12":[1166.08,359.521,0.703378,1528.09,412.567,0.733411,980.631,436.208,0.673822,659.764,456.741,0.742195,1345.6,459.6,0.731992,895.273,489.101,0.678105,580.365,533.218,0.257544,1283.75,689.225,0.499876,1734.12,733.402,0.223622,1795.89,980.592,0.0555809,1681.09,1074.83,0.0648456],"13":[1160.13,439.008,0.0764702,1516.28,530.372,0.196314,983.535,547.897,0.543447,653.902,577.364,0.655682,880.593,627.447,0.80521,600.889,686.267,0.313003,1613.47,856.961,0.100664,1260.23,868.795,0.569042],"14":[974.669,647.981,0.465162,648.036,689.252,0.638049,880.369,789.348,0.833229,600.939,809.808,0.41703,1580.98,1010.01,0.141665,1213.25,1018.88,0.64621,1663.41,1074.84,0.076733],"15":[1124.82,150.485,0.869508,1504.51,156.44,0.878404,927.496,174.034,0.370837,856.812,221.238,0.0621831,621.585,241.786,0.917391,1825.18,247.9,0.881403,1310.24,338.859,0.914034,1745.88,377.234,0.802295],"16":[1142.39,150.587,0.958235,1525.11,159.409,0.852905,930.546,174.006,0.13775,859.958,221.314,0.9495,642.178,238.881,0.869318,1834.11,247.735,0.108933,1330.78,330.13,0.111218,1772.39,397.828,0.831415],"17":[1492.74,159.449,0.567964,903.997,174.152,0.297842,1068.95,224.063,0.535875,597.994,244.66,0.8782,1790.05,247.868,0.858578,1421.95,271.437,0.540316,1260.32,342.03,0.923518],"18":[1166.1,150.462,0.915307,1542.82,171.264,0.637156,1021.84,215.334,0.331974,901.129,227.162,0.8659,648.082,238.926,0.0987843,1377.91,268.169,0.306764,1819.34,433.244,0.858218],"19":[989.444,665.68,0.120769,674.549,715.811,0.559119,821.619,812.882,0.762655,650.978,833.455,0.42398,1489.73,1024.81,0.22791,1283.71,1048.34,0.615529],"20":[962.987,650.998,0.121694,677.444,712.729,0.545488,839.321,818.779,0.748007,648.014,827.561,0.372851,1498.66,1036.55,0.219253,1283.79,1045.27,0.588761],"21":[971.792,665.614,0.374614,642.173,695.197,0.447904,886.466,809.794,0.762739,589.17,830.452,0.229458,1201.34,1030.64,0.34822,1589.85,1030.66,0.174787,1660.5,1074.84,0.0597874],"22":[1036.49,668.732,0.40357,668.602,715.634,0.124469,865.847,745.129,0.178172,648.119,833.326,0.4606,1492.65,1024.84,0.494689,1224.82,1051.34,0.162429,1218.98,1054.23,0.162428,1168.98,1074.84,0.174282,1198.4,1074.81,0.16778],"23":[1036.47,671.618,0.45803,650.994,715.785,0.112767,871.693,739.271,0.162696,639.217,836.383,0.40265,1492.73,1021.76,0.468759,1166.04,1074.81,0.239277],"24":[1007.05,671.574,0.609372,1424.99,695.172,0.0523207,624.434,700.97,0.323246,927.672,745.158,0.699705,583.314,830.54,0.387601,1586.97,1024.84,0.321146,1139.5,1051.25,0.387906]}]}
```

I need to extract only one object named "1" with its contents and save these to a new JSON file with a new name say,  "New file 1", "New file 2" ....

Or if deleting all contents except "1" and its contents, and leaving the file as it is with object "1".

Comment: what is 'object named "1"'?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov This is name of the object. There are many objects like this "0", "2", "3", and other objects like "people", "pose_keypoints_2d"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library to read the file contents into a python data structure (in this case, a nested dictionary). You can them `dump` specific parts of the JSON data out into new files.

```
import json

with open('input_json.json', 'r') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)

for k, v in data['part_candidates'][0].items():
    with open('output_json_{}.json'.format(k), 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(v, outfile)
```

Comment: This is for one file right? I have a folder of over 5000 JSON files. Would this code work in that case ?

Comment: @M.irfan this is for one _input_ file, which splits the contents of `'part_candidates'` down into individual files. There's no reason you can't extend this to multiple input files but the code won't blow up your computer if you make some attempts on your end to solve this problem yourself. Just try things out - you'll get a better understanding that way :)

Comment: @M.irfan You will get a lot of files though, so I recommend writing the output to a new directory in case it doesn't work as you expect. You need something like `os.listdir()` or `glob` in an outer `for` loop to apply this code to multiple files.

Comment: OK fine. But if you could do that, it will save my time as i am trying to catch a deadline and already working parallel in other stuff. I look forward to your additional code please. Thank you.

Comment: @M.irfan that isn't going to come. We're not here to just do all of your work for you. You will actually have to do some work yourself; the only reason I answered at all was because there was an existing answer that was incorrect. But I cannot make my example 100% applicable to your case because I'd need to actually see your whole problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

convert Json to Dictionary, using python library json

```
import json
data = json.loads(your json)
```

Than after you are done performing

```
json.dump(data)
```

Edit 1
You can access the element in a Dictionary by

```
sample_data = dict((k,data[k]) for k in ('key1','key2','key99') if k in data)
```

Comment: This wouldn't give you a list, it would give you a dictionary. You also don't address any of the actual task. And if the data is a file, `loads` is not the correct method to use either.

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail ?

Comment: @UtsavMangal Sorry i am still unable to get this. Is there any confusion in my question ?

Comment: @M.irfan can you please update, what's the output you expect

Comment: @UtsavMangal I expect a new or an updated file with the only object "1" and its contents. But remember, i need all these to be done in a loop or so as there are 6000 such files.

Comment: I am still not getting your point, can you give a example json @M.irfan